# el-popover in a v-for, open only one popover per line

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I try to open a popover when I click on the "Delete" button.

The problem is that all the popovers of all the "Delete" buttons open at the same time.

Can you help me solve this problem?

I would like the click, only the popover concerned opens. And with the button "cancel", only the button concerned closes.

Thank you !

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="student in students.data">
        <div class="col--10">
            <avatar v-bind:username="student.name" :size="36" class="col--10"></avatar>
        </div>
        <div class="t20 col--30">{{ student.name }}</div>
        <div class="t20 col--40">{{ student.email }}</div>

        <div style="text-align: right" class="col--20">
            <el-button icon="el-icon-edit" size="small" @click="editStudent(student)"></el-button>


            <el-popover placement="top" width="160"
              v-model="deleteStudentPopover">
              <p>Are you sure to delete this?</p>
              <div>
                <el-button size="mini" type="text" @click="deleteStudentPopover = false">cancel</el-button>
                <el-button type="primary" size="mini" @click="myDeleteFunction">Yes, delete!</el-button>
              </div>
              <el-button slot="reference" @click="deleteStudentPopover = true">Delete</el-button>
            </el-popover>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


export default {
    data() {
        return {
            deleteStudentPopover: false,                
            students: []
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) like example? it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<div v-for="(student, index) in students.data">` then bind/pass index when calling different functions.